# why do my exam boards use $t > 0$ not $t\ge 0$?

Tags: notation

In my mechanics exams we often have to state when $v = 0$:
$$v = t^2 + 4t -45 = 0$$
$$v = (t+9)(t-5)$$
$$\therefore t = 5 \Rightarrow v= 0 \because t > 0$$
However my tendency is to think that it should read $t \ge 0$ but all the mark schemes seem to use $t > 0$,so i thought there might be a reason we can never say $t=0$ because of some property of time,  but some other questions in the same exams refer to $t=0$. Is there some reason for this? or is the exam board just being weird?

(posted this on maths and not physics due to it being covered in my mechanics class as part of my further maths A level, is it in the right place?)

Comment: maybe because they don't care if v=0 at t=0?

Comment: At time t seconds, a particle has position with respect to an origin O given by the vector $$r = ({8t}\choose{10t^2 - 2t^3})$$ where $(1\choose0)$ and $(0\choose1)$ are perpendicular unit vectors east and north respectively and distances are in
metres.

Comment: Mostly because we are interested in the time after we begin the timer, not the instant it starts, usually we care about the next times it happens.

Comment: In most examples on projectile motion a negative time refers to a nonphysical moment in time before the projectile was fired so it tends to be ignored, after sufficiently advanced physics courses discrete time symmetry changes this

Comment: okay, thank you (I now feel the question is answered but was answered in comments how do i mark it as "solved" so others don't assume it to be ongoing?)

Comment: Someone would have to develope the comments into an answer that's acceptable to you or alleviates your concerns. If you'd like I can write down what I said in answer form though brief it is

Comment: yes that would be appreciated, it may be short but i think it answers the question properly anyways.

Comment: Most of the times we assume that the parts starts at rest $u=0$ at origin.So,$v=0$ at $t=0$ is trivial.Also,there can be some significances of time coming negative .

Comment: For eg.assume we are throwing a projectile at a height of $5m$ above the ground (ground is taken as zero level) and using $s=ut-\frac{1}{2}gt^2$ we find out when displacement $s=0$.Here we get one positive and one negative answer.Positive answer indicates that the ball will truely hit the ground at that time and negative indicates that if the ball was following the same motion before we started taking note of time (remember we started counting time after we threw the ball at a certain height from the ground) then in was also at ground at that many seconds before we started taking note of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in order to expand on the comment, the choice of using $t>0$ vs $t\ge 0$ mostly depends on context since the laws of classical mechanics are deterministic (related to the time symmetry comment I made), in other words a negative time means we can follow a particles trajectory backwards in time even before we started keeping time at the zero mark and it follows physical rules perfectly fine. However most of the time we are interested in times after we start our time keeping of the system, it's common for projectiles to be fired from tops of buildings and so when one solves, for example, when the projectile is at ground level we arrive at one positive time and a negative time. These are often mentioned to students as nonphysical answers to the question because "time can't be negative." Of course it really means you can't follow the particle backwards because it didn't exist before being fired. Later courses cover this deterministic nature of physics (quantum systems are special in this regard) and the time symmetry which does away with such strange notions of the limits on our time variable.

Comment: Of course this is actually still suited more towards physics than math, this will at least hopefully help in your question.